# Can I grow Linux VMware partition with RAID 1 below?

Tags: linux, raid, vmware

0

Imagine I have rootvg design as below:

```
/dev/sda 
    |___ /dev/sda1
    |___ /dev/sda2
    |___ /dev/sda3  30G [part]
           |___md1   30G   [raid 1 ] 

/dev/sdb
    |___ sdb1
    |___ sdb2
    |___ sdb3     30G [part]
           |___md1   30G   [raid 1 ]
```

I've extended both disks from vmware side by 10GB each

```
/dev/sda ---> 40GB
/dev/sdb ---> 40GB
```

'fdisk -l' show new disk sizes -OK.

Can I grow size of partitions /dev/sda3 & /dev/sdb3 so that 'mdadm --grow max' can see unallocated space and extend my RAID1 to maximum?

Is this even possible to do it online? I don't want to destory partition table and create bigger parts as this is my rootvg :) Or maybe I need to double the size of current disks, create partitions with same size as my current ones and then grow via mdadm?

I am really stuck with this. Sorry for newbie question! Please help me with good advise!

Answer (score 0):

This should actually work seamlessly - two possibilities:

- Extend the partitions and the RAID
- Create new partitions in the empty space, create a new RAID there and add it as a second PV to your VG

The latter version is zero risk.

Comment: Hello Eugen, new RAID from new partition is a solution I was looking for. Thanks a lot!